# Delete all remote branches that don't exist locally anymore

Tags: git

I have a git repo where I pushed my latest changes to a remote. In the last days I deleted several branches locally but couldn't remove them on the remote, since I didn't have any connection to the git server.

Is there a way to delete the remote branches, which don't exist anymore on my local repo? We talk about 200 branches, so a manual approach is not desired.

I found several answers to delete a local branch, that does not exist on the remote anymore via `git fetch --prune`, in my case I am looking for the other way around.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+prune+remote+branches+

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437928/7976758: [`git push --prune origin`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---prune)

Comment: Upvote the linked answer, that would be enough.

Comment: @phd but it doesn't answer my question. I was looking for the --prune option

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437928/7976758) starts with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove multiple branches one single command you can try this,

```
git push origin --delete <branch1> <branch2> <branch3>
```

If you want the list of the remote branch you can try this command first. Then just copy-paste the list into the above command.

```
git branch -r
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Since we talk about 200 branches, I was looking for an automated way.

Answer (score 0):

## Current Answer

I didn't read the comments. the best is the answer at [stackoverflow.com/a/13437928/7976758](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437928/9002634):

```bash
$ git push --prune origin
```

## Previous Answer:

Stumbled onto this question, here's how I did it, it's not exactly automated but this should be a start.

### Step 1: Delete local branches

1. Get list of local branches

```bash
$ git --no-pager branch --sort=-committerdate   > branches_to_delete.txt
```

2. Delete the rows not to be deleted in file `branches_to_delete.txt`
3. delete the branches at local

```bash
$ cat branches_to_delete.txt | xargs git branch -D
```

### Step 2: Delete remote branches

1. Get list of remote branches

```bash
$ git remote prune origin # delete all the local refs to already-deleted remote branches
$ git --no-pager branch -r --sort=-committerdate  > branches_to_delete.txt
```

2. delete branches not to be deleted in file `branches_to_delete.txt`
3. replace all "origin/" with "" (vim, emacs, vscode, sed, etc.) in file
4. delete the branches at remote:

```bash
$ cat branches_to_delete.txt | xargs git push origin --delete
```